# Whitelist certain IP in Debian postfix/courier mailserver

Tags: postfix, smtp

On a debian jessie mailserver with postfix and courier I want to whitelist certain IPs, that are blocked somehow (those IPs are from an openvpn provider) so I can send out mails with that server.

I already tried to remove temporarily all reject rules in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and restarted postfix, but I was still blocked to send mails.

If I don't use another VPN exit, sending mails works fine with Thunderbird.

Where else can I search for the reason, I am blocked?

I use STARTTLS on port 587 to send out mails.

Comment: I assume you're talking about outgoing SMTP although this is not completely clear (you mention reject rules from `main.cf`). Postfix doesn't usually "block" or otherwise reject its own outbound connections (after all, you've probably configured it to connect there!) so what makes you think Postfix is blocking these outbound connections to port 587?

Comment: Yes outgoing smtp.. maybe I am completely wrong and something before blocks the ip? Firewall? I am a bit stuck and don't know where to search for the reason